# Sign app in XCode with another developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, sign, iphone-developer-program

I have a client that doesn't want my apple developer account to interfere with his application. So, can I use his developer account(without the credentials) to sign and test an application?

I searched and I found myself lost with some questions over a possibility that I'm not sure it works. The thing I found was him exporting the developer profile via XCode, sending me the developer profile file and me importing that into my XCode. 
What I did not understand, however, was:

1. will this thing work?
2. will I need his account id and password for importing this, afterwards? (because this would be a problem)
3. is it required for him to generate this through XCode or is there any alternative?
4. can we both use this after he exports the file and I import it? is he able to revoke me after this is finished?

Edit: 
Is there any other way to acheive that? Maybe any third party application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy :

Get the p12 of his certificate : he could export from his keychain
then install this certificate and adhoc provisioning profile in you system. You can use this for taking build .

Comment: Can you provide me with more detailed steps?

Comment: Dude? You still here?

Comment: Yeah sure  for each certificate you create in developer portal there is a keychain certificate request associated  with it, this is why to install a provisioning profile in your system you need to get the p12 version of that certificate from the generated system. What you could do is ask that person to install the certificate in his system after generating them in developer portal and find that certificate in his keychain right click export it along with private key ad .p12 then get that p12 and provisioning profile from him and double click and install in your system.

Comment: and then i would be able to build a solution? okay, i'll give it a try. what do i have to do with provisioning profile? just double click and it will install?

Comment: yeah , get the provisioning profiles(both adhoc and development) with the device UDID s added

Comment: after i try to install the .p12 certificate, there is a password request.

Comment: while exporting p12 certificate there is step for entering password which could even be skipped ask the one who exported the password whether he entered any password

Comment: I guess it worked. When you have time you should edit your post and give more details in it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to build apps that appear to be signed by him without having his credentials. You only need this if you will be the one producing the release builds. For simple development you can use your own account.

There are various ways you could split up the work if he is capable of producing a build himself or running command line tools to re-sign the app you build (I haven't tried this myself). In my experience the company will have an account shared among developers permitted to produce and submit apps rather than individuals.

1. Not the way you hope it will work. When you import the profile you will be asked for a password.
2. You need his password to use his private key.
3. The developer profile is a convenient way to do it. He can send you the distribution certificate and a separate p12 file containing his private key along with his password for that key. You will import it into your keychain by double clicking the files and entering his password. Or he can give you his apple ID and password, and you can add that account in your Xcode preferences. This will give you access to the provisioning and distribution profiles.
4. You can both use the credentials at the same time. No, it is not revocable. Once you have his credentials it will be up to you to remove the account information. You will have his private key in your keychain.

Comment: Yeah, I know about him generating an ipa file for me, but this won't work in this situation. So there isn't any other temporary way in which I could debug with his account without his id&pass?
Maybe a third party application?

Comment: If you don't need to distribute the app to anyone, you don't need his credentials. You can sign it with your own profile and run it in the Simulator. That would allow you to debug.

Comment: I already know that, but I'm still curious if I can do it as he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. Hope my answer helps you.

Your client can add you as a team member in his developer program. He can limit the access by choosing the appropriate role as mentioned in the below link.
https://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/index.php

You can then login with your credentials and create certificates/profiles/add devices etc but you can be restricted to access his iTunes Connect.

Comment: the problem in what you say is that he wants my account not to take part in this whatsoever.